# Why isn't my response data being decoded into my type?

Tags: node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

My socket sends data to the client. I need to decode the response into this type (**Swift**):

```
class Msg: Decodable {
   var msg: String
}
```

my socket code on client (**Swift**):

```
    socket.on("Message for me") { data, ack in
        do {
            guard let dict = data[0] as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
            let noti = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict["msg"])
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Msg.self, from: noti)
            print("Message from socket: \(decoded)")
        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

my **node js** server is sending:

```
  io.to(socket.id).emit('Message for me', {msg: `only socket: ${socket.id} can see this`});
```

I keep getting the following error in my client, and after several tries several different ways I haven't figured out why.

```
Invalid top-level type in JSON write
```

I've tried using `JSONSerialization.data()` and `JSONSerialization.jsonObject()` and I keep getting the same error. I even checked some of the other similar posts and still nothing. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: in your socket code client, could you add `print("--> data: " + String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just before "do", to try to see what you get from your server.

Comment: @workingdog I'm getting back `Message for me with data: [{
    msg = "only socket: ....... can see this";
}]`

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I got it to decode as expected after removing this line:
`guard let dict = data[0] as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }`.

I guess Swift's serializer and decoder was all that I needed in this instance.